# Marking a forum thread as read?

Tags: php

I'm working on a custom forum and was wondering what people would consider as the best approach to marking a thread as read.

I want to display a post icon for the threads and if the thread hasn't been read it has an unread icon and the topic title is bold. If its been read then the topic title is normal font weight and the post icon changes to the read icon.

Would the best way be to store in the users session which threads they have viewed and set it up to mark all threads older than 48 hours or so as read?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a second table such as:

```
thread_member: thread_id, member_id, read_flag, posted_flag, bookmarked_flag
```

Basically anything specific to that member and a thread could go in there. When pulling the list of threads, LEFT JOIN against that table. If read_flag is `0` or `NULL`, then it's new.

```
SELECT * FROM thread t
LEFT JOIN thread_member tm ON t.id=tm.thread_id AND tm.member_id=$member_id
WHERE t.id=$thread_id
```

Anytime somebody posts a message in the thread, just run this query:

```
UPDATE thread_member SET read_flag=0 WHERE thread_id=$thread_Id
```

posted_flag could be used to determine if the person wrote a message in the thread.

bookmarked_flag could be used to determine if the person bookmarked the thread.

To keep the table trim, you could truncate all old records that didn't have any important flags set. In this example, you could delete all records older than X days/weeks/months that don't have bookmark_flag set.

Comment: While this does seem to be an intelligent way to do this, I wonder what you gain from performing an update on (possible) hundreds of records each time a post is made, rather than doing a data comparison. You should already know when the last post to the thread was - it seems to me you're essentially just replacing a date with an int, but doing more work in the process. Are you really cutting down on the table size much at all?

Comment: A fair point, but I doubt there would be any significant penalty doing it this way considering forum replies are not probably very frequent. (Also, adding `AND read_flag=1` would limit the number of updates.) I prefer the flag simply because it matches the other types of data (it could even be condensed into a bitfield) while accurately describing its purpose, but if somebody were to prefer a timestamp, I wouldn't argue against it.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, I would keep a separate table that holds the userId, the threadId, and the lastVisted Date/Time. Simply Add/Update the appropriate userId/ThreadId record when the user views a thread.

Then, when a visitor views a thread, you know any posts made after the user's lastVistedDate are new and obviously, if there is no LastVisted date, you know all of the posts in a thread are new.

Answer (score 2):

Maintain a table of datetimes a user has last visited a thread

viewed_threads

columns: user_id, thread_id, datetime

Also make sure to keep track of the last time threads were updated

When a user opens a thread

```
replace into viewed_thread ( user_id, thread_id, datetime ) values( $user_id, $thread_id, now() )
```

Now when listing threads you can check the user session for the datetime the user last visited that thread. if the last-viewed datetime is before the last time the thread was updated then it's "new"

Comment: Thanks. Wont the table become a bit lengthy though?

Comment: The table does get big, but you can truncate it at whatever interval is appropriate. On any small-to-medium sized site, you should be able to be quite liberal, assuming you've got indexes in place and enough RAM to be effective, etc.

Comment: I would imagine the table wouldn't get too large in file size, we're only talking about 3 small fields - it may, however, become large in record count. Just as long as you don't pull in all of the records you should be ok. If you need to pull a list of threads, simple `SELECT thread_id, lastVisted from threadViews where thread_id in (x1, x2, x3) and user_id=xxxx`